# Column Validation Formula works in Excel but not in SharePoint

Tags: column

It seems like the tip was to create your formula in Excel and then just copy it to sharepoint. So I did and it doesn't work so I was just wondering if someone could tell me why.

I've trying to validate a phone number so that the user must enter it in (xxx) xxx-xxxx format. (Yes I know there are other formula's that people us), but my question is, why does this work in Excel but not in SharePoint (2013)

=IF(ISBLANK(A1),TRUE,EXACT(A1,(TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(",""),")","")," ",""),"-",""),".",""),"(000) 000-0000"))))

Answer (score 0):

SUBSTITUTE doesn't exist in SharePoint. You'll need to use REPLACE.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/results.aspx?ctags=CH001171117&queryid=df92b950-8c64-4f3d-8121-4f1a991ceec2&avg=osu